# Why am I getting a 500 internal error when updating indexableText?

Tags: google-drive-api

I have a file (which happens to have no content) on Drive, and I'm trying to update its indexableText. Sadly, instead of a happy smiling 200, I'm getting a sad face 500.

Request ...

```
PUT https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/0Bw3h_yCVtXbbTndiNFFkLUEwWlk?useContentAsIndexableText=false&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

Content-Type:  application/json
Authorization:  Bearer ya29.AHES6ZQcOn0zqZoxM_4Wrpj00xPIb2BuDjAai0qLUnE6-JVdxMUsDg
X-JavaScript-User-Agent:  Google APIs Explorer

{
 "indexableText": {
  "text": "foofoo barbar"
 }
}
```

Response...

```
500 Internal Server Error

- Show headers -

{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "internalError",
    "message": "Internal Error"
   }
  ],
  "code": 500,
  "message": "Internal Error"
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the internal error is being triggered because when I initially inserted the file,  useContentAsIndexableText=true. I guess Drive doesn't like the idea that a file's contentAsIndexable state can ever change.

Having got past that, I'm now hitting 
[Update file seems to not be able to update indexableText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19322314/update-file-seems-to-not-be-able-to-update-indexabletext)