# Update file seems to not be able to update indexableText

Tags: google-drive-api

From a series of tests, it seems that indexableText can only be set once. Once set, subsequent updates are ignored.

Here is what I've tried and observed...

1. Insert a new file with indexableText. Search works.
2. Insert a new file without indexableText. Then update the file with
   some indexableText. Search works.
3. Insert a new file with indexableText. Then update the file with some
   different indexableText. Search fails, ie. searching for the old
   text returns the file, but searching with the new text doesn't.

In all cases, useContentAsIndexableText=false and the updates all return 200.

Bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

and the answer is ...

asynchronicity (the album The Police **should** have made).

It seems that the initial indexing of a document happens almost instantly. However re-indexing changes takes a few minutes (around 5 in my specific instance).

hth somebody.